# How to introduce oneself in relation to ones husband?

Tags: word-choice, formality

I know there are a few ways to essentially say "wife" (妻、家内、女房). Can they be used by a speaker to refer to themselves?

Examples I thought of:

> （私はAの）妻／家内／女房です。
>
> 妻／家内／女房の○○です。

I have a feeling one can't use 奥さん, かみさん, because of the さん. I've almost never heard 家内 or 女房 used in real life, either.

**How does one introduce oneself in relation to ones husband?**

Related: [How to introduce myself in relation to my wife?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43405/how-to-introduce-myself-in-relation-to-my-wife)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

口頭でしたら、

> （はじめまして。+）
>   「妻の花子です。/ 太郎の妻です。/ 山田の妻です。」
>   「家内の花子です。/ 太郎の家内です。/ 山田の家内です。」
>   （+（いつも）主人がお世話になっております。）

のように言えると思います。（「家内」を使うのは正しくない、という人もいますが、実際には結構使われています。）でも、

> 「山田です。（いつも）主人がお世話になっております。」

というふうに、「妻」「家内」などの言葉を使わずに、少し遠回しに表現することも多いと思います。

または、ご主人が、

> 「あ、（こちら）妻/家内<sup>(1)</sup>です。」

と言って、そこで奥さんが、

> 「（はじめまして。）（花子です。）（いつも）（主人が<sup>(2)</sup>）お世話になっております。」

のように言う形もよく見られると思います。

<sub>注</sub>
<sub>(1) 関西の人は「妻」「家内」の代わりに「嫁」を使うことも多いです。

カジュアルな場面では、「これ、（うちの）かみさんです。」と言ったり、「奥さん」「うちのやつ」（関西ではよく「嫁さん」「嫁はん」）を使ったりします。</sub>
<sub>(2) フォーマルな場面では、自分の夫を苗字で呼んで、「いつも山田がお世話になっております。」のように言うこともあります。少し年配の人が使う表現かもしれません。</sub>